# Add values in a cell and place in totals field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the values the user enteres into the Slots cell in each row.  I want to get the totals and place it in the SlotsTotals field.  But, the code is not working at all.

```
function checkRow(){
    var table = document.getElementById('tblSample');

    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++){
            document.getElementById('SlotsTotals').value += document.getElementById('txtSlots' + i).value;
    }
 }
```

I'm dynamically adding rows to a table.  The user will input values into the slots field.  I want to loop through the table to get a total of all the values and add then total to the SlotsTotal field.

Here is my some of my html to add the rows.

```
function addRow() {
    //function ValidateRow(){alert('error');}
    //function insertRow();

    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;  
    // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
    //var iteration = lastRow;
    var iteration = lastRow;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(6);            
    var element5 = document.createElement('input');            
    element5.type = 'text';            
    element5.name = 'txtSlots' + iteration; 
    element5.id = 'txtSlots' + iteration;   
    element5.size = 10;
    cell5.appendChild(element5);
  }
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: It's not giving an error. It's not working at all.

Comment: Try posting a complete example. `table.lastRow` seems wrong, and so does your `for` loop.

Comment: I apologize for having table.lastRow because I'm not using that at all so I removed it.

Comment: @tnbumbray When you open up your developer console, does it not show you an error of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you post some of your html code please

maybe try

```
document.getElementById('SlotsTotals').innerHTML
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

__

maybe this can help :)

```
<table id='tblSample' style='border: 1pt, solid, black;'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ...A1
    </td>
    <td>
      ...A2
    </td>
    <td>
      ...A3
    </td>
    <td>
      ...A4
    </td>
    <td>
      ...A5
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='txtSlots1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ...B1
    </td>
    <td>
      ...B2
    </td>
    <td>
      ...B3
    </td>
    <td>
      ...B4
    </td>
    <td>
      ...B5
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='txtSlots2'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ...C1
    </td>
    <td>
      ...C2
    </td>
    <td>
      ...C3
    </td>
    <td>
      ...C4
    </td>
    <td>
      ...C5
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='txtSlots3'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      ...D1
    </td>
    <td>
      ...D2
    </td>
    <td>
      ...D3
    </td>
    <td>
      ...D4
    </td>
    <td>
      ...D5
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='txtSlots4'>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
      ...E1
    </td>
    <td>
      ...E2
    </td>
    <td>
      ...E3
    </td>
    <td>
      ...E4
    </td>
    <td>
      ...E5
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='txtSlots5'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type='button' onclick="test();" value="test">
<input type='text' id='SlotsTotals'>

<script>
  function test(){
    var table = document.getElementById('tblSample');
    res = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    sum = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
      s = res[i].id
      if((String(s).indexOf("txtSlots") > -1)&&(res[i].type == 'text'))
      {
        sum += parseInt(res[i].value)
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('SlotsTotals').value = sum
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am adding dynamically adding rows to a table.  Here is some of the code that does that.var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
 var lastRow = tbl.rows.length; 
 // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
 //var iteration = lastRow;
 var iteration = lastRow;
 var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

var cell5 = row.insertCell(6);            
var element5 = document.createElement('input');            
element5.type = 'text';            
element5.name = 'txtSlots' + iteration; 
element5.id = 'txtSlots' + iteration; 
element5.size = 10;
cell5.appendChild(element5);

Comment: i dont see where the value is set?

Comment: The value is not set.  The user will input a value into the Slots field.  I want to calculate the values in the Slots field on each row within the table and then place the total in the SlotsTotals field.

Comment: I tried your suggestion this morning and I'm getting a NaN.  What does that mean?

Comment: Ok...I have looked at this almost all day and it's still not working correctly.  I want to loop through my table for the value that is in cell(6) of every row.  It's not doing it correctly.